# Randomly select 30% of the sum value in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python pandas and have a data frame that is pulled from my CSV file:

```
ID          Value
123         10
432         14
213         12

'''

214         2
999         43
```

I want to randomly select some rows with the condition that the sum of the selected values = 30% of the total value.

Please advise how should I write this condition.

Comment: It is expected to be exactly 30% or would "close to 30%" work?

Comment: @mozway Thank you! "close to 30%" works

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, be aware that the answer below might fail if a single value can be over the 30%, this might not happen with a large dataset. Let me know if this is a case and we can find alternatives ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first shuffle the rows with [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), then filter using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and comparison to be ≤ to 30% of the total:

```
out = df.sample(frac=1).loc[lambda d: d['Value'].cumsum().le(d['Value'].sum()*0.3)]
```

Example output:

```
   ID  Value
0  123     10
3  214      2
2  213     12
```

Intermediates:

```
    ID  Value  cumsum   ≤30%
0  123     10      10   True
3  214      2      12   True
2  213     12      24   True
1  432     14      38  False
4  999     43      81  False
```

Comment: Prefect one-line code. This is exactly what I need